# Why Odoo creates a succeeding Empty record in tree view, when we open a popup window in form view?

Tags: odoo, record, odoo-8, popupwindow

Below is my code to open popup window

XML FORM BUTTON :

```
    `<button name="%(action_import_inventory)d" string = "Import File"   class="oe_highlight" type="action"/>'
```

PopUp window :

```
    `<record id="action_import_inventory" model="ir.actions.act_window">
     <field name="name">Import Beneficiaries Payments List</field>
     <field name="res_model">beneficiary_list.beneficiary_list</field>
     <field name="view_type">form</field>
     <field name="view_mode">form</field>
     <field name="view_id" ref="view_import_inventory"/>
     <field name="context">{'default_id': context.get('record_id', False),}   </field>
     <field name="target">new</field>
     </record>`
```

Popup Window Form View:

```
    `<record id="view_import_inventory" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">import.bene.form</field>
        <field name="model">beneficiary_list.beneficiary_list</field>
        <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Import Inventory">
            <label string="Please Upload CSV file with beneficiarses payments detasls. Columns Formats- Firstname,Lastname,Account,Amount" colspan="4"/>
                <group colspan="4" col="6">
                    <field name="data" filename="filename" colspan="4"/>
                    <field name="filename" invisible="1"/>
                    <!--field name="delimeter"/-->
                </group>
               <separator string="" colspan="4"/>
            <footer>
                    <button class="oe_highlight" special="cancel" string="Cancel"/>
                    <button name="action_import" string="Import" type="object" />
                    <button name="download_sample_csv" string="Download Sample Csv" type="object"/>
          </footer>
           </form>
        </field>
    </record>`
```

Every time i click on the popup window button, a window is opened which is what i want but a new empty record is also created in tree view. Can anyone tell me why it is happening and how to prevent odoo from creating a new empty record.

Comment: Post a screenshot with your issue. And also, when does the new record get created? When you click on the `Import File` button to open the popup or when you click the `Import` inside the popup?

Comment: @GeorgeDaramouskas. When i click on Import inside popup at that time a new empty record is created.